# How to create uniform interface to build for builders in builder patterns, if one of concrete builders take extra argument?

Tags: c++, inheritance, builder, virtual-functions

```
class Builder 
{
  public:
   virtual void Build(int a) = 0;
};

class ConcreteBuilder1 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a);
};

class ConcreteBuilder2 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a. struct A* a);
};
```

So My question is how to design Build() method to take both parameters(int, struct* A). But with same builder interface ?

So that,

```
int x;
struct A* y;
Builder concrteBuilder1 = new ConcreteBuilder1(); 
concrteBuilder1 ->Build() // //  Here I am  forced to pass struct A* a eventhough not needed for concerte builder1 . And I am also forced to forced to change Builder interface too.
```

My apologies if I did not convey the question clearly.

Comment: I have updated the code for more clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builder usually builds an object of another class. You may try something similar to this:

```
class ToBuild
{
    //some code here
};

class Builder
{
public:
    virtual ToBuild * build() = 0;
};

class ConcreteBuilder : public Builder
{
    int _valA;
    int _valB;
public:
    ToBuild * build() override
    {
        ToBuild * obj = new ToBuild();
        //initalize obj using _valA and _valB variables;
        return obj;
    }
    
    ConcreteBuilder& valA(const int val)
    {
        _valA = val;
        return *this;
    }
    
    ConcreteBuilder& valB(const int val)
    {
        _valB = val;
        return *this;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
     ConcreteBuilder b;
     ToBuild * obj = b.valA(1).valB(2).build();
     //some code
     delete obj;
     return 0;
}
```

[edit]
You can write another derived class with as many parameters as you want and still use a single 'build' method.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
using Builder::Build;
```

to the derived class's declarations. This will import this symbol into the derived class, and make both it, and the derived class methods, of the same name, available to overload resolution. I.e.

```
using Builder::Build;

void Build(int a);
```

I'm ignoring the fact that you can't construct the derived class anyway, since it fails to implement this pure virtual function from the base class.

Comment: Sorry my code was wrong. Please see updated code. My problem is with Build()  function which is forcing me to send extra parameter for one concrete builder and not for another concrete builder. Because of this I may to have to passnull pointer (struct A*) for concrete builder1 as default argument.

Answer (score 1):

Derived class override their functions from the one which has same parameters and same return value.

So if you declare a function like...

```
class Builder 
{
  public:
   virtual void Build() = 0;
};

class ConcreteBuilder1 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a);
};

class ConcreteBuilder2 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a. struct A* a);
};
```

Here, Build function in ConcreteBuilder1 class treated as a new function, not override function.

So try this.

```
class Builder 
{
  public:
   virtual void Build(int a, A* b = 0) = 0;
};

class ConcreteBuilder1 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a);
};

class ConcreteBuilder2 : public Builder
{
  public:
    void Build(int a, struct A* a);
};
```

I wish it's helpful for you.